# Display slideToggle is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a slideToggle section and it work perfectly but I don't do what when I click on #login bottum section comes down and go up fast and I can't show it this is my code

```
$("#login").click ( function() {  $("#loginForm").slideToggle(600) } )
```

and HTML

```
<section class="content bgcolor-1" id="loginForm" style="display:none">
    <h2 class="nomargin-bottom" id="test">ورود به حساب کاربری</h2>
    <%= form_for "user" , :url => {controller: "user", action: "login"}, :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
    <span class="input input--haruki">
        <%= f.text_field(:email, :class => "input__field input__field--haruki" ) %>

        <label class="input__label input__label--haruki" for="input-2">
            <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--haruki">ایمیل</span>
        </label>
    </span>
    <span class="input input--haruki ">
        <%= f.password_field(:password, :class => "input__field input__field--haruki" ) %>
        <label class="input__label input__label--haruki" for="input-2">
            <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--haruki">رمز عبور </span>
        </label>
    </span>
    <%= f.submit("ارسال", :class => "buttom") %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: You have not accedently defined $("#login").click twice?

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN I don't think so ,, but i check it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event could be bubbling up. Try this

```
$("#login").on('click', function(event) {  
 event.stopPropagation();
 $("#loginForm").slideToggle(600) 
} );
```

Comment: it's not worked :(  `$("#login").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    return $("#loginForm").slideToggle(600);
  });`

Comment: so thank sir ,,, i write your code in .coffee and it's worked ,,,